# Nest ElasticSearch MatchPhrase Behavior When Phrase Not Found

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, match, nest, match-phrase

Using an ElasticSearch Nuget to search Kibana logs in a given field called Message.

#### What I Want to Do

##### Verify Text Not There

I want to search for the "Don't Find This" sub-string inside the Message field.
I want to verify the string is absent.

##### Verify Text Present

I want to search for the sub-string "Here it is" inside same field.
I verify it is present.

#### What Worked

The second test was successful using the Match() function.

#### What Did Not Work

The first test failed.  It returned 10 records because, it seems, they contained "Don't" or "Find" or "This".

A quick search suggested that I would have to change indexing or create a custom analyzer, but I don't understand the repercussions of this, i.e., what effect will it have on the currently working test?

In the code below is where I tried *MatchPhrase* instead of *Match*.

I was surprised to see that using *MatchPhrase* caused the originally working test to fail.

```
            ISearchResponse<LogRecord> searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<LogRecord>(s => s
                .AllIndices()
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Must(m =>
                        {
                            var mustClauses = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<LogRecord>, QueryContainer>>();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                                mustClauses.Add(mc => mc.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Message).Query(message)));
                           
// a list of other fields here...

                            mustClauses.Add(mc => mc.DateRange(dr => dr.Field(f => f.Time).GreaterThanOrEquals(startDate ?? DateTime.MinValue).LessThanOrEquals(endDate ?? DateTime.Now)));

                            return m.Bool(b1 => b1.Must(mustClauses));
                        })
                        )
                    )
                );
            return searchResponse;
```

I have a SpecFlow feature file where I specify what to verify as present or absent as follows:

```
    Then log has
        | Message                         |
        | some raw request before sending |
        | Start Blah Blah transaction      |  
        | sg_blahblah                      |
        | sg_Year                          |
        | sg_EmployeeNumber                |
    And log does not have
        | Message         | 
        | this_works_fine | 
        | this_works_too  |
        | No good         |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure about your DSL need.

If I understand correctly, it should be something like this:

```
POST _search
{
  "query":{ 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "Message"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "some raw request before sending"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "Start Blah Blah transaction"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "sg_blahblah"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "sg_Year"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "sg_EmployeeNumber"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "Message"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "this_works_too"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "this_works_fine"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase":{
            "my_message_field": "No good"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can also use `filter` to boost performance if the keyword only has 1 word; or add `slop` to adjust granularity (see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html).

I wrote all in `match_phrase` because it seems there would be a lot of keywords with spaces in your case.

And then append those `match_phrase` clauses to your `Clauses`.

Comment: MatchPhrase, in fact, does work for me, and it was a matter of waiting longer for the results to appear.

Comment: Depends on data structure, architecture and scenarios, maybe can try something like: (a) narrow down indices instead of using `AllIndices()`.  (b) check sharding, routing strategies; check nodes capacities. (c) use `transform` to dump out aggregated data into new indices to improve future use. (d) adjust mappings / templates to make some less-important data to be a `keyword`. (e) Adjust from source: add more tags to categorize data would make queries easier and faster.